# How to replace thumbnail with new one of dropzone js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am working with dropzone js and i need to upload only one file. After file is uploaded and thumbnail is generated, i need that "Upload now" button text replace to "Replace image". After click this button do new upload and old thumbnail replace with new. Now plugin thumbnails insert from left to rights in a row.

This is my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y90kv9e4/12/)**

```
Dropzone.options.upload = {
  maxFilesize: 2,
  dictFileTooBig: 'Image is bigger than 2MB',
  acceptedFiles: 'image/*'
};
```

thank you